# Can r10k use a control repository on the local filesystem?

Tags: puppet, r10k

I'm starting to work with R10k for deploying Puppet environments, but I don't want to put our control repo into GitHub, and I don't have a local GitLab server at the moment.

I've tried using the following sources stanza:

```
:sources:
  mysource:
    basedir: /tmp/puppet-test/environments
    prefix: false
    remote: /srv/git/control.repo
```

When I run `r10k deploy display` I get the correct values displayed, but no environments. I have two branches in my repo, though, both with Puppetfiles and the rest.

Is R10k able to work with a remote that is accessed via files? Do I need to prepend a file:// scheme?

Answer (score 1):

This configuration works for me as a `r10k.yaml` (using r10k 2.3.0):

```
---
:cachedir: /var/cache/r10k
:sources:
  :local:
    remote: file:///opt/repos/r10k
    basedir: /etc/puppet/environments
```

The repository does not need to be a bare repository.